# AngularJS auto function

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I have a problem with AngularJS. In my HTML I have something like this:

```
<tbody ng-repeat="show in pastShows">
    <tr>
        <td><input value="{{show.address}}" type="text" id="addressUp" class="form-control" placeholder="address"></td> 
        <td><input value="{{show.price}}" type="text" id="priceUp" class="form-control" placeholder="XX euros"></td> 
        <td><button type="button" class="btn btn-success" ng-click="updateShow({{show.id}})">Update</button></td> 
    </tr>
</tbody>
```

I have the function `updateShow` in his controller, but if I send the variable using `{{show.id}}` the function doesn't work. To try it I did this in the function:

```
$scope.updateShow = function(id){
  alert(id);
}
```

Someone has any idea??
Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the curly braces:

```
<td><button type="button" class="btn btn-success" ng-click="updateShow(show.id)">Update</button></td>
```